# how to filter the posts of a page by message_tags (API Graph Facebook v3.3)

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Hello I am currently in training and I have to make requests through the Facebook API. I have to search on a page the posts, for a given tag (s) or hastags and for a given period. For each posts I have to recover among others its statistics. I have an application token that allows me to query on the API.

I use API 3.3 under a node server 10.16 and express 4.17.1. I do not use an SDK.
I manage to collect posts for a period. But I can not filter posts by tags or hastags and I can not get post statistics

I try with https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

get/v3.3/{page.id}/posts?fields=message_tags,message,created_time,permalink_url,attachments,reactions&ids={tag id}

get/v3.3/{page.id}/posts?fields=message_tags,message,created_time,permalink_url,attachments,reactions&ids={tag id}&from={page.id}

get/v3.3/{page.id}/posts?fields=message_tags,message,created_time,permalink_url,attachments,reactions&message_tags.id={tag id}

It's been 3 days since I'm on it and I'm getting lost in the documentation. Thanks for your help

Comment: you have to get all posts and filter on your own

Comment: it is a limitation related to the application token or API directly ?

Comment: it is a limitation of the api

Comment: Ok thanks you, for the statistics is you as which fields I have to select as for example the persons affected by posts

Comment: i am not sure what you mean, to be honest. take a look at the api reference for page insights for statistics, they can be read per post.